# Как сохранить наглядность очерёдности создания снимков по времени после изменений в репозитории?

Tags: git, phpstorm, git-bash

[image: Как сохранить наглядность очерёдности создания снимков по времени?]

На **рис. 1**: то, что получилось.
На **рис. 2**: желаемый результат.

Comment: Это вопрос исключительно визуализации. Эти два рисунка могут соответствовать одной и той же истории.

Comment: Так а чем вы визуализацию делаете?

Comment: А вполне может быть и первый вариант, хотя логически автор предполагает второй. Например, если он сильно ребейзил "добавленную ветку". Конечно, если сильно-сильно поребейзит, то можно и время поменять, но нужно ли оно?

Comment: Git не даёт привязку по времени. Только по хешу (в котором учитывается время, но это для вас не важно). **Прочитайте книгу!**

Comment: @0andriy привязка по времени то есть, но после ребейза она "немножко теряется" и меняется на текущую.

Comment: @0andriy а что вы понимаете под «привязкой»? В коммите аж две даты сохраняются вместе с author и committer.

Comment: @KoVadim, *привязка по времени то есть, но после ребейза она "немножко теряется" и меняется на текущую* — в таком случае, вероятно, поможет опция `--author-date-order` команды `log`

Comment: @akp а придумано всё это вроде как специально для разработки Линукса, где в былые времена автор изменений мог прислать их по почте ревьюеру, а тот уже коммитил. То есть и личность и время автора и коммитера могли сильно отличаться.

Comment: @akp *я так понимаю, что дата по «autor» никогда не меняется,* - может также поменяться. В гите все может поменяться.

Comment: для "нормально пользователя" - по просьбе, для "всех остальных" - "я случайно нажал и все пропало".

Comment: @akp проверил `commit --amend` – нет, дата автора остаётся. Но если вы коммит пересоберёте вручную, например `git reset --soft HEAD^; git commit`, то конечно дата будет новая. Вообще, поменяться может всё, но только от конкретных действий конкретных людей. Если беспокоитесь, просто не давайте кому попало прав на переписывание ветки `master`.

Comment: К слову, как посмотреть на обе даты: `git cat-file -p <revision>`, например `git cat-file -p HEAD`

Comment: @NickVolynkin Дата авторства не является указателем на то, что этот комит сделан раньше или позже в дереве. Более того, как я указал, даты даже не две, а три, просто одна является входным параметром при создании хеша. https://alexpeattie.com/blog/working-with-dates-in-git

Answer (score 1, accepted):

например, упорядоченность по дате, указанной в коммите, можно визуализировать с помощью опции `--date-order`. здесь коммиты создавались попеременно в двух ветках, справа для примера приведён вывод без этой опции:

```
$ git log --all --graph --decorate --oneline --date-order 

с опцией --date-order:        без опции:

* c0429c3 (HEAD -> new) 10+   * c0429c3 (HEAD -> new) 10+
| * 708f32d (master) 10       * ea02ba7 9+
* | ea02ba7 9+                * 887b82f 8+
| * 9752cd2 9                 * f8ac4ac 7+
* | 887b82f 8+                * 755028b 6+
| * 0a39580 8                 * 4752a25 5+
* | f8ac4ac 7+                * 04343d9 4+
| * 0085d68 7                 * 6139c2c 3+
* | 755028b 6+                * ae19249 2+
| * c4e9c93 6                 * 8d8b5bc 1+
* | 4752a25 5+                | * 708f32d (master) 10
| * 99ac799 5                 | * 9752cd2 9
* | 04343d9 4+                | * 0a39580 8
| * e47ed8e 4                 | * 0085d68 7
* | 6139c2c 3+                | * c4e9c93 6
| * 0bbadf8 3                 | * 99ac799 5
* | ae19249 2+                | * e47ed8e 4
| * 33cc7dc 2                 | * 0bbadf8 3
* | 8d8b5bc 1+                | * 33cc7dc 2
| * 2a233f6 1                 | * 2a233f6 1
|/                            |/
* 73b7914 0                   * 73b7914 0
```

---

подробнее — в [`$ man git-log`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html)

---

если по каким-то причинам (см. обсуждение под текстом вопроса) дата в коммитах не соответствует дате их создания, то вместо опции `--date-order` можно попробовать опцию `--author-date-order`.

Comment: Отличный ответ. Вы для него специально наделали поочередных коммитов с сообщениями-числами? Возможно, стоит добавить код для воспроизведения — чтобы каждый мог поэкспериментировать.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, да, даже написал очень сложную программу: `for i in $(seq 1 10); do git co master; dt >> file; git ci -am $i; sleep 1; git co new; dt >> file; git ci -am "$i+"; sleep 1; done` // ci, co — это мои alias-ы для commit и checkout

Comment: @NickVolynkin, dt — это у меня alias оболочки: `$ alias dt='/bin/date +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S"'`. но здесь он не нужен, просто по привычке так наполняю тестовые файлы. про остальное — я дополнил пред. комментарий.

Comment: *без --date-order ветка new оказывается «наверху» графа не потому, что она новее, а потому, что репозиторий на нее переключен (т.е. HEAD)* — у меня переключение веток не влияет на их порядок: new всё равно показывается выше master-а, независимо от указателя HEAD. именно потому, что там последний коммит.

Comment: @akp, *внесите сразу в ответ опцию --author-date-order* — это сделано за сорок минут до вашего комментария. // *Научить бы ещё PHPStorm с этой опцией показывать* — баг-репорт им отправьте. если в документации ничего не найдёте.

Comment: @akp, я видел: вам уже объясняли, что это две совершенно разные даты. но для подавляющего большинства существующих в мире коммитов они совпадают. несовпадение — редкая ситуация, про неё написано в конце.

Comment: @akp, редкость вашей ситуации — в несовпадении дат (даты совершения коммита автором и коммитером). а описанное в вопросе — вполне универсально. и у других людей, ищущих ответ на вопрос про визуализацию очерёдности коммитов в разных ветках, с огромной долей вероятности будет вполне «стандартная» ситуация. на них ответ в первую очередь и рассчитан.